# Prevent segue in prepareForSegue method?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

Is it possible to cancel a segue in the `prepareForSegue:` method?

I want to perform some check before the segue, and if the condition is not true (in this case, if some `UITextField` is empty), display an error message instead of performing the segue.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

It's possible in iOS 6 and later:
You have to implement the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

In your view controller. You do your validation there, and if it's OK then `return YES;` if it's not then `return NO;` and the prepareForSegue is not called.

Note that this method doesn't get called automatically when triggering segues programmatically. If you need to perform the check, then you have to call shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier to determine whether to perform segue.

Comment: FYI, if the segue is triggered programmatically by calling [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil]; shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier will never get called.

Comment: @Thedude thanks for pointing this out.  Was tracking down an issue and it wasn't hitting my breakpoint.  For anyone curious, you just need to call this method wrapped in an if statement to get the same result.

Comment: @jpittman would you please explain what do you mean wrapped in an if statement?

Comment: @AubadaTaljo: (apologies for formatting)  `if ([self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil]) { [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:nil]; }`

Comment: Tried this in iOS 11.3 SDK from a storyboard segue and "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" did get called automatically

Answer (score 53):

*Note: the accepted answer is the best approach if you can target iOS 6. For targeting iOS 5, this answer will do.*

I don't believe it is possible to cancel a segue in `prepareForSegue`. I would suggest moving your logic to the point that the `performSegue` message is first sent.

If you are using Interface Builder to wire up a segue directly to a control (e.g. linking a segue directly to a `UIButton`), then you can accomplish this with a bit of refactoring. Wire the segue to the view controller instead of a specific control (delete the old segue link, and then control-drag from the view controller itself to the destination view controller). Then create an `IBAction` in your view controller, and wire the control to the IBAction. Then you can do your logic (check for empty TextField) in the IBAction you just created, and decide there whether or not to `performSegueWithIdentifier` programatically.

Comment: If the segue is to a popover controller, you do *not* want a second tap of the button to create another popover controller; the correct thing to do in this case is to dismiss the popover. Your answer allows  for this proper behavior. If you wire it directly from the button in the storyboard, I don't see anyway to get the proper behavior.

Comment: After several frustrating hours of trying to get multiple segue-based popovers to play nicely together, I gave up and got rid of the popover seques in favor of this solution.  It actually uses less code.

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of having segues?

Comment: The fact to link ViewController to ViewController solved my problem. Thank you! 
This is the best solution

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 3**:
func **shouldPerformSegue**(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                 sender: Any?) -> Bool

Return value **true** if the segue should be performed or **false** if it should be ignored.

**Example**:

```
var badParameters:Bool = true

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if badParameters  {
         // your code here, like badParameters  = false, e.t.c
         return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, it's somewhat bad behavior to offer a button that a user shouldn't press. You can leave the segue wired as stands, but start with the button disabled. Then wire the UITextField's "editingChanged" to an event on the view control ala

```
- (IBAction)nameChanged:(id)sender {
    UITextField *text = (UITextField*)sender;
    [nextButton setEnabled:(text.text.length != 0)];
}
```

Comment: "Alternatively, it's somewhat bad behavior to offer a button that a user shouldn't press".
I would disagree with this - this is partially true but really depends on context.  It is also bad behaviour not to guide the user - for example so they can tap a button and the system explain what needs to be done first.  With a disabled or invisible button users will either get lost or call support...

Answer (score 11):

Its easy in the swift .

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

Comment: Huh? Can you elaborate more on this answer? Code-only answers are not very useful for further readers...

Answer (score 9):

[As Abraham said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818366/419348) check valid or not in the following function.

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(nullable id)sender
{
     // Check this identifier is OK or NOT.
}
```

And, the `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` called by programming can be blocked by overwriting following method. By default, it is not checking valid or not by `-shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`, we can do it manually.

```
- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check valid by codes
    if ([self shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender] == NO) {
        return;
    }

    // If this identifier is OK, call `super` method for `-prepareForSegue:sender:` 
    [super performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender];
}
```

Comment: is this part about `[super performSegueWithIdentifier:identifier sender:sender];` really true?

Comment: @BenWheeler You can try it. If you override `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method, and not call it's `super` method.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4 Answer:

Following is Swift 4 implementation to cancel segue:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "EditProfile" {
        if userNotLoggedIn {
            // Return false to cancel segue with identified Edit Profile
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Should Perform Segue for Login Register

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{

    [self getDetails];

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"])
    {

        if (([_userNameTxtf.text isEqualToString:_uname])&&([_passWordTxtf.text isEqualToString:_upass]))
        {

            _userNameTxtf.text=@"";
            _passWordTxtf.text=@"";

            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *loginAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Invalid Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Try Again" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [loginAlert show];

            _userNameTxtf.text=@"";
            _passWordTxtf.text=@"";

            return NO;
        }

    }

    return YES;

}

-(void)getDetails
{
    NSArray *dir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *dbpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/userDb.sqlite",[dir lastObject]];

    sqlite3 *db;

    if(sqlite3_open([dbpath UTF8String],&db)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Fail to open datadbase.....");
        return;
    }

    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from user where userName = \"%@\"",_userNameTxtf.text];

    const char *q=[query UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *mystmt;

    sqlite3_prepare(db, q, -1, &mystmt, NULL);

    while (sqlite3_step(mystmt)==SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        _uname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(mystmt, 0)];

        _upass=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",sqlite3_column_text(mystmt, 2)];
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(mystmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to Kaolin's answer is to leave the seque wired to the control but validate the control based on conditions in the view. If you're firing on table cell interaction then you also need to set the userInteractionEnabled property as well as disabling the stuff in the cell.

For instance, I've got a form in a grouped table view. One of the cells leads to another tableView that acts as a picker. Whenever a control is changed in the main view I call this method

```objective-c
-(void)validateFilterPicker
{
    if (micSwitch.on)
    {
        filterPickerCell.textLabel.enabled = YES;
        filterPickerCell.detailTextLabel.enabled = YES;
        filterPickerCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        filterPickerCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
    else
    {
        filterPickerCell.textLabel.enabled = NO;
        filterPickerCell.detailTextLabel.enabled = NO;
        filterPickerCell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        filterPickerCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other way is to override method of tableView with willSelectRowAt and return nil if you don't want to show the segue. 
`showDetails()` - is some bool. In most cases should be implemented in data model being represented in cell with `indexPath`.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
        if showDetails() {
                return indexPath            
        }
        return nil
    }
```