# ios segue "cancel"

Tags: ios, segue

Depending on an XML return, I don't want the current `segue` to perform on UIButton touch.

I know I can pick which `segue` I want to *perform*, but how to I make a `segue` **not** perform? Or at least **not perform** any of the available `segues`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your deployment target is iOS 6.0 or later, you can override [the `-[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW111) to return `YES` if you want to perform the segue and `NO` if you don't.

If your deployment target is earlier than iOS 6.0, you won't receive the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` message.  So in your storyboard, don't draw the segue from the button.  Instead, draw the segue from the button's view controller and give the segue an identifier.  Connect the button to an `IBAction` in its view controller.  In the action, check whether you want to perform the segue.  If you want to perform it, send yourself [`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW83), passing the identifier you assigned to the segue in the storyboard.

Comment: is `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier" sender:self];` correct? Xcode's giving me a `SIGABRT` :(

Comment: You need to set an exception breakpoint to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

[Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW111) has the correct method to cancel a segue that is managed within the StoryBoard:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

For example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"listPopover"]) {
        if (self.listPopover == nil) {
            // Allow the popover segue
            return YES;
        }
        // Cancel the popover segue
        return NO;
    }
    // Allow all other segues
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` message was added in iOS 6 and will not be sent on devices running an earlier version of iOS.  When this question was posted, iOS 6 had not been released.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42161944/4791032

You can just check it in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`