# prepareForSegue : how can I set an if-condition?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

This may be very rookie but...

I've set a segue between two `ViewControllers` in my `Storyboard`, with the identifier `clickBtn`.

Now I'm calling it this way in my code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"clickBtn"])
    {
        if(conditionVerified)
        {
            SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
            [controller setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
        }
        else
        {
            // If I enter here I get the error below
        }
    }
}
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Link''

In fact I don't want to do this transition if I enter the else-statement. How to do so?

Comment: Which textField? Or better where is the text field?

Comment: I think error in code where you are trying to create managed object. Is it in SecondViewController init method? Please, show us this code.

Comment: [self managedObjectContext] is nil I suppose. Where do you set that?

Comment: @opedge That's it but in fact, I'm facing this problem because I don't want to do this segue if I enter the else-statement.

Comment: @alecnash Yes my managedObjectContext is nil because I'm pushing the view in any case, but what I don't know to do is how to avoid doing this segue if conditionVerified is false.

Comment: @Rob I think you should set segue identifier in Storyboard and then manually perform this segue after your check: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:<your segue identifier> sender:nil];

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent segue in prepareForSegue method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066525/prevent-segue-in-prepareforsegue-method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than having the button perform the segue have it call a method like the following.

```
-(IBAction)mySegueButtonMethod:(id)sender
{
   if(conditionVerified){
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"clickBtn" sender:sender];
   }
   else{
        // do not perform segue and do other relevant actions.
   }
}
```

The error you are seeing is because i am assuming controller is calling something that needs context manager not to be nil.

You can't really stop the segue from occurring once you are in the method prepareForSegue as it will always perform the segue at the end of the method.

Comment: Not really the best answer. Part of the reason for using segues is that there is no need to hook up action methods for simple things such as button taps or table view cell selections. The other answers that use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` are much more in keeping with this.

Answer (score 16):

To optionally suppress a transition, implement

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
```

and return `YES` or `NO`, depending on your condition. In your example:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"clickBtn"])  {
        return conditionVerified;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

In `prepareForSegue:` it is "too late" to suppress the transition.

Comment: Nice answer. But please note that `segue` is not there in the context of method. Just use [identifier isEqualToString:@"clickBtn"].

Answer (score 4):

You should refactor your code differently for this purpose. Implement `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` like below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    return [identifier isEqualToString:@"clickBtn"] && conditionVerified;
}
```

It would prevent the segue "clickBtn" to be executed if the condition is not verified, i.e. `conditionVerified` is false. Now use:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"clickBtn"] && conditionVerified) { //just a double checking
        SecondViewController *controller = (SecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        [controller setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}
```

And this would prepare your segue for execution, only if `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` return YES(true). So you would never have to face any unintended transition if condition is not verified.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try This .It worked for me!

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"Login"] && condition )
        { 
            return YES;
        }
        else if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"SignUp"])
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OOPS!!" message:@"Incorrect Username Or Password" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

            return NO;
        }

    }
     return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to use the method `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` as mentioned here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12818366/2500457