# Swift prevent storyboard segue from happening

Tags: swift, storyboard

**Intro**

I am creating a `Swift 2.0` app in which an action can be performed only a certain number of times, say 8. In order to accomplish this behavior, I need to cancel a certain segue, `performAction`, should it be triggered via pressing a button linked to it on storyboard.

**Research**

I ran across questions like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066525/prevent-segue-in-prepareforsegue-method](http://this), which suggested code like:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

     return true
 }
```

**Implementation**

I implemented it like:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: "createCard" ,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    if amountOfTimes > 8 { //To be triggered if the segue should be cancelled
        return false
    } else {
    return true
    }
}
```

However I get the error

> Expected ',' seperator

How can I have the segue be cancelled should `amountOfTimes` be greater than 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your identifier is `"createdCard"` use the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`method like this:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String ,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return !(identifier == "createCard" && amountOfTimes > 8)

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Will try once I am at a computer again.

Comment: You should prefer `return !(identifier == "createCard" && amountOfTimes > 8)` instead of an unnecessary `if`.

Comment: you're 100% right @Sulthan will edit the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this phrase:

```
identifier: "createCard"
```

That is not Swift. This is not a function *call*, it is a function *implementation*. You must say:

```
identifier: String
```

`identifier` is not a value you *set*, it's a value you *receive*. You can then *look* to see if it is `"createCard"`, but you do not get to *claim* that it is.

Answer (score 0):

[image: 1]
Click on First ViewController's Round Yellow/White icon (highlighted left side in image) and hold drag to next ViewController (ex. SubmitOTPVC).
Then write this code in swift file:

```
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "otpVC", sender: nil)
```

here `otpVC` is the identifier name of segue.