# "func prepareForSegue" not calling for CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, swift3

Is It possible to use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` to  catch the movement of segue with following method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?){
}
```

Here is my view controller code :

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let poke:Pokemon!

    if inSearchMode {
        poke=filterPokemons[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        poke=pokemonlist[indexPath.row]
    }
    shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("PokemonDetailVC", sender: poke);
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "PokemonDetailVC" {
        if let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as? PokemonDetailVC{
            if let poke = sender as? Pokemon {
                detailVC.pokemon=poke;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Storyboard segue reference**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
```

Instead of:

```
shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier("Identifier", sender: self)
```

When we use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` we can catch the movement of segue with following method:

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool
```

Check this link: [Prevent segue in prepareForSegue method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8066525/prevent-segue-in-prepareforsegue-method)

Comment: No `sender` is okay, just change the method to `performSegueWithIdentifier .`

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier` instead of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` because `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` method gives you an opportunity to prevent a segue from happening. Returning NO from this method causes the segue to fail to perform.

If you want more detail about `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:)

Where as `performSegueWithIdentifier` method allows to pass data from the source view controller to the destination view controller.

So now just call `performSegueWithIdentifier` like this instead of `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`.

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("PokemonDetailVC", sender: poke)
```

**In Swift 3.0**

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "PokemonDetailVC", sender: poke)
```